# Microsoft Bot Framework Geolocation

Tags: c#, geolocation, botframework, chatbot

How do I get a users geocoordinates with the Bot Framework? I know I have to use entities but am not sure how to actually get the coordinates and not define them.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no **automatic way** of getting user's location because **it will violate user privacy**.

However, you can always request for user's location. Depends on the chat channel they're using, they might be able to send you their location (I tested on **telegram**)

As a starting point, you might need to read about

### How to send location

Sample Code:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply();
reply.ChannelData = new TelegramCustomMessage
{
    Method = "sendLocation",
    Parameters = new Parameters
    {
        ChatId = "your_chat_id",
        Latitute = 0,
        Longitute = 0
    }
};

public class TelegramCustomMessage
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parameters")]
    public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "chat_id")]
    public string ChatId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "latitute")]
    public float Latitute { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "longitute")]
    public float Longitute { get; set; }
}
```

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html#customtelegrammessages

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation

### How to extract geolocation from activity

Sample Code:

```
if (entity.Type == "Place")
{
    Place place = entity.GetAs<Place>();
    GeoCoordinates geoCoord = place.Geo.ToObject<GeoCoordinates>();
    // geoCoord object will contains Longtitude & Latitude
}
```

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html#places

Comment: would it be possible for you to put a snippet for the same in Node.js?

Comment: @PirateApp: sorry I don't know anything about NodeJS :).

Comment: Place entity can came for Facebook channel as well. However, Facebook doesn't provide a way to request user's location. The only way to do it is just ask through a text message.

Comment: Are you sure the `sendLocation` can be used to **request** a user's location instead of **send** a location to user? Do you have a working example?

Comment: @EugeneBerdnikov Absolutely not, "sendLocation" **can't be used to request user's location**. However, you can use it to prompt user, something like *"is this your current location?"* or *"is this where you want to go to?"*. For requesting user's location, you have to ask the user using normal text message.

Answer (score 0):

The team just added support to the Framework for location services. Super helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location